# NSAttributedString and emoji: the range I never set seems to be set

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring, emoji

This is the most weird problem (XCode 10.2.1 playground):

```swift
let a = "String with emoji "
var b = "00:00 0000"

var nsa = NSMutableAttributedString(string: a)
var nsb = NSMutableAttributedString(string: b)
nsb.addAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.red], 
                  range: NSRange(location: 0, length: nsb.length))
nsa.append(nsb)
```

and the `nsa` looks like this:

[image]

The `00` after the emoji has the same width and height as the emoji character. But it gets weirder. The effect is extended only over digits 0-9, space, and hash (#) characters. If I replace the `00:00 0000` with a different string then everything is perfectly normal:

[image]

It seems like internally `NSMutableAttributedString` applies an attribute to the emoji character and then incorrectly extends it to the attached string's prefix composed of certain characters.

Is this a known problem? I found a workaround by appending a thin non-breaking space character to the first string `a + "\u{2009}"`. Is there a better way of dealing with emoji weirdness in Swift?

Comment: What's weird is the string display incorrectly even if you remove the call to `addAttributes`. Simply appending these two strings is a problem.

Comment: The result looks correct to me in an UILabel, displayed in the iOS simulator, so this seems to be a problem the Xcode Playground.

Comment: If you create a UILabel with that attributed string, it's fine. It's only an issue in the playground display of the attributed string.

Comment: It happens with UITextView in playground. Have not tried in an emulator.

Comment: Even if it does just turn out to be Playgrounds, I really encourage opening a defect at bugreport.apple.com. Playgrounds should display this correctly.

Comment: @RobNapier Thanks for the pointer. I've filed the bug report. I'll update the question when/if Apple responds.

Answer (score 2):

The display issue happens in the playground display of the attributed string. It also happens if you use the attributed string in a UITextView. But the problem does not happen in a UILabel.

All of the display issues go away if you give the attributed string a font.

Adding:

```
nsa.addAttributes([.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)],
    range: NSRange(location: 0, length: nsa.string.utf16.count))
```

after appending the two strings makes the all of the issues go away. Obviously you should use whatever desired font you want.

You should always apply a font to an attributed string so the UI components know how to properly display the content of the attribute string.

Comment: using utf16 is actually recommended for strings that contain emoji (since the weird lenghts of "characters”), thanks for pointing this out! this answer helped me resolve my issue with NSAttribiutedStrings and emojis. cheers

Answer (score -1):

Here is Apple's official answer:

> We have determined that this is an issue for you to resolve.
>
> Since the app is not explicitly specifying the font to the attributed
>   string, it’s relying on the font fallback system.
>
> It is recommended to specify the font attribute all the time since the
>   contextual nature of the text system might produce unexpected result
>   like this.
>
> Please let us know whether the issue is resolved for you by updating
>   your bug report.

This is just appalling.

Comment: Apple has been quite clear, including in a WWDC 2018 video, that you should not rely on the default attributes to work as you expect. Sure, this may come as a suprise, and it may be a little annoying, but rmaddy has already told you the answer, so there's probably no warrant for gratuitous emoting. You've learned something useful; isn't that what we're here for?